# Build solution with multiple projects

Tags: msbuild

I have following project in one solution.

1. MVC Web Project
2. WPF Project
3. Library project common to both projects.

How can I build above projects & publish the output for MVC Web & WPF project to some directory using MSBuild command?

Answer (score -2):

What you want is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org). Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information.